# How can I tell if a QFileDialog was closed without selecting a file?

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days and haven't figured it out yet. Basically I am using a QFileDialog to select a file but if i close the window with out choosing a file the program crashes. How do i tell if there was no file selected? Here is the code i am using:

```
QFileDialog loadFile(this);
loadFile.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);


QString filename = "";


loadFile.exec();
```

This is the code i use to get the chosen file.

```
selectedFiles = loadFile.selectedFiles();

filename = selectedFiles.at(0);
```

I tried using 
    {if (dialog.selectedFiles.at(0) != "" }
to see if there was no selected file but it does not work. If I select a file it will run the code in the if statement just fine.

Thanks a ton or any help!

Comment: The `exec` function returns a [DialogCode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#DialogCode-enum).

Comment: You should be checking if selectedFiles is empty (e.g. `if (!selectedFiles.isEmpty())`) before you ever try to get the first element.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm almost certain that not selecting a file and yet accepting the selection will trigger the `Accepted` state regardless of the missing selection.

Comment: @rbaleksandar I just tested it on windows (Qt 5.5) and I can't accept the dialog if I don't select a file. The "Open" button is ignored with an empty selection.

Answer (score 4):

If you close the dialog without selecting a file, your list `selectedFiles` is empty and if you try to access an element you get a crash (the function is not safe for invalid index).

What you want is to check if the user selected anything or not.

```
QString filename;

QFileDialog loadFile(this);
loadFile.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
loadFile.exec(); // You could check the return value here to see if the user canceled or not
QStringList selectedFiles = loadFile.selectedFiles();

if (!selectedFiles.isEmpty()) 
{
    filename = selectedFiles.at(0);
    // Do something with the filePath...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is check the return value of exec() like follows...

```
if( !loadFile.exec() )
{
    // The user pressed the cancel button so handle this accordingly
}
else
{
    // At least one file was selected because the user cannot click the 'open' button unless a file selection has been made so continue as normal
}
```